# Recursive triggers on update MariaDB

Tags: sql-server, mariadb

I have two virtual servers.

On both servers, I have a table "users".

I have an update trigger on the table "users" on both servers so when one server table is updated, it should be updated on the second server as well.

I've searched for a long time and everyone says "MySql does not do recursion. Period.". This is true if both tables are on the same server or db.period.

So when I try to update one table row it gives me an error:

```
"Error Code : 1159
Got timeout reading communication packets";
```

When I add IF statement that won't update anything in one trigger or another, no errors are shown.

One way to do this is by adding one field that will tell us whether or not we should update row using the trigger. I would like the MariaDB version of `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL` available in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` tag from you question since it unrelated to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL`  is **sql-server** related.

Comment: Master-master replication with `replicate-do-table=xxx` is what you need.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity and added to `sql-server` tag back for answers familiar with both,

Comment: DanGuzman Thank you!
@Kondybas What I wrote here is an arbitrary example. In reality, I don't have identical tables on both servers, thus replication is not an option.